Is the graph quotient a colimit?
Let $\mathcal{Grph}$ be the category of undirected simple graphs with self-loops allowed. A morphism in $\mathcal{Grph}$ between two graphs $f:G \rightarrow H$ as a map on the vertex set that preserves local connectivity, i.e.
$$u \sim_{G} v \Rightarrow f(u) \sim_H f(v) \, .$$
Note that self-loops can only be mapped to self-loops and that if the image $f(u)$ does not have a self-loop, then we cannot collapse neighbouring nodes in the preimage, i.e.
$$f(u) = f(v) \text{ and } f(u) \nsim_H f(u) \Rightarrow  u \nsim_G v \, .$$
Now, we define the quotient graph with respect to the map $f$ as the graph $H/f(G)$ defined via:

The vertex set is given by the corresponding set-quotiont $V(H / f(G)) = V(H) / f(G)$
Two vertices are adjacent if and only if there are representatives in the domain graph that are adjacent, i.e.
$$ u \sim_G v \Rightarrow [u] \sim_{H / f(G)} [v] \, .$$

Note that the node $f(G)$ in H/f(G) has a self-loop if and only if $G$ has at least one edge (i.e. is not totally disconnected).
Constructions like this in an abstract setting, tend to coincide with the cofiber of the morphism $f$, by which I mean the following pushout
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
G @>{f}>> H \\
@VVV @VVV \\
1 @>>> P
\end{CD} \, ,$$
where $1$ denotes the terminal object. In our category $\mathcal{Grph}$, the terminal object is a single vertex with a self-loop. The cofiber of $f$ in $\mathcal{Grph}$ almost coincides with the quotient graph above, except that it adds a self-loop even if $G$ is totally disconnected. More precisely, denoting the single vertex with no self-loop by $K_1$ we observe that
$$
H / f(G) = 
\begin{cases}
\operatorname{colim}(1 \leftarrow G \xrightarrow{f} H ) & \text{if } G \text{ contains an edge,} \\
\operatorname{colim}(K_1 \leftarrow G \xrightarrow{f} H ) & \text{else.}
\end{cases}
$$
In general, we also cannot replace $1$ by $K_1$ because a map $G \rightarrow K_1$ exists if and only if $G$ has no edges.
So my question now is: Can the quotient graph, as defined above, be written as a single colimit without this case-distinction?

This sounds like it's related to quotient spaces in topology: Quotienting a space by the empty set is that space plus a disjoint point, and it is very clear that this is the correct version (otherwise some homology formulas fail). Now it's happening to the edges here.

I don’t know if you’d count this as a “single colimit without this case-distinction”, but at least this is functorial. Abusing the notation a bit, we shall let $V(\cdot): \mathcal{Grph} \to \mathcal{Grph}$ be the functor that sends a graph to the totally disconnected graph with the same underlying vertex set. Then $\iota: V \Rightarrow \text{Id}_{\mathcal{Grph}}$ s.t. $\iota(G): V(G) \to G$ is the identity map on the underlying vertex set is a natural transformation. Now, $H/f(G)$ is the colimit of the following diagram:
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
K_1 & & \\
@AAA & & \\
V(G) @>V(f)>> V(H)\\
@V \iota(G) VV & & \\
G @>f>> H
\end{CD}
